# How can I set the x-axis tick locations for a bar plot created from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple plot, with x labels of 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2 etc. up to 15:

[image]

The plot was created from a `pandas.DataFrame` without specifying the xtick interval:

```
speed.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15, 7))
```

Now I would like the x-interval to be in increments of 1 rather than 0.25, so the labels would read 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

I'm sure this is easy but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

I've found `plt.xticks()` which seems like it's the right call but maybe it's `set_xticks`?

I've changed the x ticks a great amount without doing what I wanted up until this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you create that plot?

Comment: I made it using a pandas DF, `speed.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15, 7))` but made no stipulations as to the xtick interval

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way that pandas handles x-ticks for bar plots can be quite confusing if your x-labels have numeric values. Let's take this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 21)
y = np.random.rand(21)
s = pd.Series(y, index=x)

ax = s.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10, 3))
ax.figure.tight_layout()
```

[image]

You might expect the tick locations to correspond directly to the values in `x`, i.e. 0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 1.0. However, this isn't the case:

```
print(ax.get_xticks())
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
```

Instead pandas sets the tick *locations* according to the *indices* of each element in `x`, but then sets the tick *labels* according to the *values* in `x`:

```
print(' '.join(label.get_text() for label in ax.get_xticklabels()))
# 0.0 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5 0.55 0.6 0.65 0.7 0.75 0.8 0.85 0.9 0.95 1.0
```

---

Because of this, setting the tick positions directly (either by using `ax.set_xticks`) or passing the `xticks=` argument to `pd.Series.plot()` will not give you the effect you are expecting:

```
new_ticks = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)       # 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0
ax.set_xticks(new_ticks)
```

[image]

---

Instead you would need to update the positions and the labels of your x-ticks separately:

```
# positions of each tick, relative to the indices of the x-values
ax.set_xticks(np.interp(new_ticks, s.index, np.arange(s.size)))

# labels
ax.set_xticklabels(new_ticks)
```

[image]

This behavior actually makes a lot of sense in most cases. For bar plots it is common for the x-labels to be non-numeric (e.g. strings corresponding to categories), in which case it wouldn't be possible to use the values in `x` to set the tick locations. Without introducing another argument to specify their locations, the most logical choice would be to use their indices instead.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Can the Matplotlib features like `AutoDateLocator` help in this situation?

Comment: hmmm... the default behavior was changed, probably in matplotlib. I can't find ant documentation for this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJqde.png

Comment: hmmm2....: This is probably a bug/regression in Pandas 1.2.0 that will be fixed in 1.2.1: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38865