# Cannot combine bar and line plot using pandas plot() function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting one column of a pandas dataframe as line plot, using plot() :

```
df.iloc[:,1].plot()
```

and get the desired result:

[image]

Now I want to plot another column of the same dataframe as bar chart using

```
ax=df.iloc[:,3].plot(kind='bar',width=1)
```

with the result:

[image]

And finally I want to combine both by

```
spy_price_data.iloc[:,1].plot(ax=ax)
```

which doesn't produce any plot.

Why are the x-ticks of the bar plot so different to the x-ticks of the line plot? How can I combine both plots in one plot?

Comment: I'm not sure why the x-ticks are different as they shouldn't be.  Regarding getting a line and a bar chart on the same plot you can use subplots.  I'll submit an answer

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100209/how-can-i-set-the-x-axis-tick-locations-for-a-bar-plot-created-from-a-pandas-dat) for your first question, it might help.

Comment: The problem of getting right xticks was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22623488/6845924)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

some data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2))
print (df)
          0         1
0  0.008177 -0.121644
1  0.643535 -0.070786
2 -0.104024  0.872997
3 -0.033835  0.067264
4 -0.576762  0.571293
```

then we create an axes object (ax).  Notice that we pass ax to both plots

```
_, ax = plt.subplots()

df[0].plot(ax=ax)
df[1].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please try to do the trick with this DF: `df=pd.DataFrame({'v1':np.sin(np.arange(50)), 'v2':np.cos(np.arange(50)**2)}, index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=50, freq='30T'))` ?

Comment: I tried this: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2))
ax = plt.subplots()
df[0].plot(ax=ax)
df[1].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)`  and got : 
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_figure'`

Comment: @MaxU Did you try what I have above?  Did it only plot one series?

Comment: @BobHaffner, yes, the second plot completely overwrites the first one

Comment: @MaxU Same here.  Give this a go `_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(75,50))

plt.plot(df.index, df['v1'])
plt.bar(df.index, df['v2'], width=.01)`

Comment: @user1934212 make sure you have `_, ax = plt.subplots()`  ax is a tuple (of a figure and an axes) they way you currently have it. Or if you prefer `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

Comment: @MaxU Shoot, it works for me using matplotlib 1.5.1.

Comment: @BobHaffner, hmmm, i've the same version: matplotlib: 1.5.1, pandas 0.18.1, Python: 3.5.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123646/discussion-between-bob-haffner-and-maxu).