# Data not showing properly on pandas bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

My plot which looks like this seems obstructed and isn't showing the months

[image]

Here's my code

```
fname = pd.read_csv('airlines.csv')
fname.plot(kind='bar', x= "Month", y = "Minutes Delayed.Weather",
           title = "Minutes Delayed Due to Weather 2003-2016", legend=False)
```

How do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100209/how-can-i-set-the-x-axis-tick-locations-for-a-bar-plot-created-from-a-pandas-dat